# Построение графиков в Matplotlib с помощью linspace

Tags: python

Предположим

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, N)
t = function
plot(t) #соответственно построится на N отсчетах вместо х
```

Как мне теперь построить эту же функцию, но на большем интервале, чтобы N отсчетов функции t совпали с первыми N отсчетами этой же функции на большем интервале?

```
x = linspace(0, 10*pi, M)
y = function
plot(y)
```

Comment: Ну наверное `M` должно быть равно `N*5`. Поскольку конечное значение последовательности в 5 раз больше, чем для `N`

Comment: @alexlz, нет, это не так. отрезок делится на N (M) равных частей и получается что расстояние между точками разное. примерно так выходит -
http://s58.radikal.ru/i159/1203/5b/d2bda611f1f3.png

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужны одни и те же значения в двух диапазоных, то лучше использовать arange вместо linspace. Линспейс равномерно распределяет точки, так что в разных диапазонах они не совпадут. arange создаёт точки в заданном диапазоне с заданным шагом, так что при одинаковом шаге эти всегда будут одни и те же точки.

```
x1 = arange(0, 2*pi, n) #n - шаг, по умолчанию 1  
t = f1(x1)  
plot(t,x1) # лучше явно задать зависимость, а не полагаться на отсчёты  
x2 = arange(0, 10*pi, n) # главное - сохранить шаг  
y = f2(x2)  
plot(y,x2)
```

В принципе, если у вас достаточно много точек, то того же эффекта можно добиться и на линспейсе, просто явно задав зависимость в графике:

```
plot([x,t],[x,y])
```

Comment: да, я думал про arange, но хотелось бы с линспэйсом.

в целом можно первую функцию через линспэйс оформить, 2ую - через arange. 

linspace(a,b,N) - для первой

arange(a,c,t) - для второй, где t = (a+b)/N

если так сделать, то всё равно что-то не получается или я ошибаюсь, где-то лоханулся?)